# Mpdf issue: Why not work mpdf format,margin,fontsize mPDF\mPDF class value

Tags: mpdf

My mPDF Class

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['utf-8', 'A4-L', 1000000, 'cursive', 100000000000000, 100, 100, 0, 0, 0, 'L']);
```

I have use mPDF Update version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> try it

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
    'tempDir' => __DIR__ . '/pdfdata',
    'mode' => 'utf-8',
    // 'format' => [24, 24],
    'format' => 'A4',
    'margin_left' => 0,
    'margin_right' => 2,
    'margin_bottom' => 2,
    'margin_top' => 2,
    'float' => 'left'

]);
```